# Can gen-class override a protected Java method?

Tags: clojure, gen-class

I'm trying to use Swing from Clojure, and I'm getting confused by `gen-class` and I can't tell from the documentation if this is supposed to work - `paintComponent` is a protected method on `JPanel`, and I'm able to override it, but when I try to call the exposed superclass's method, I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: parentPaintComponent for class project.PicturePanel` . Can anyone clarify why I don't seem to have access to this method?

```
(ns project.PicturePanel
  (:gen-class
    :extends javax.swing.JPanel
    :name project.PicturePanel
    :exposes-methods {paintComponent parentPaintComponent}))

(defn -paintComponent [this g]
  (println this)
  (println g)
  (.parentPaintComponent this g))
```

Comment: Are you aware of seesaw? https://github.com/daveray/seesaw

Comment: I'll give seesaw a shot, but I sure would like to understand the Java interop stuff better.

Comment: Hmm, I just tested this and it worked perfect well for me. Can you provide more details about your project setup and calling code? Did you use AOT compilation?

Comment: A. Webb - thanks for the hint! It turns out that "lein run" was not recompiling the class, so I was in a funny state where the new paintComponent method was getting interpreted but the rest of the class was an old, out of date binary. After I re-ran "lein compile project.PicturePanel", things started working!

Answer (score 2):

Yes! The code works correctly if you make sure that your compiled .class files are up to date. Try recompiling them!